# Delete word in textbox

Tags: c#

user write some sentence in textbox then i want to delete word in sentence after that save the file.

for example user write

```
hi my name is john
```

it should be output

```
hi my is john
```

```
string lines = saveTxtBox.Text;
string newLines;
//string removedBreaks = Line.Replace("\r\n", replaceWith).Replace("\n", replaceWith).Replace("\r", replaceWith);
newLines = lines.Replace("name"," ");
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
sfd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    ToTxt(newLines, sfd.FileName);
}
```

but its just save the file i cannot delete name word.

Comment: are you sure that it is having "YNATEXT." in  "lines"?

Comment: You have to set the new text back to saveTxtBox.Text

Comment: why not saveTxtBox.Text="";

Comment: The code you've given does nothing to  remove the word "name", what have you researched?

Comment: i guess he is replacing some word with blank space @Sayse

Comment: In the above code you only replace "YNATEXT." which means that you must have that as the last word, as long as I write "Hi YNATEXT my name is" it won't replace since I don't have a period in the string.

Comment: @Neel - We know nothing about where the op wants to output this to, how they define what text should be removed (and how), or even what kind of application this is (I presume winforms but who knows).

Comment: oo sorry my mistake change YNATEXT. to name but stil not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this, it worked just fine.

```
        string lines = saveTxtBox.Text;
        string newLines = lines.Replace("YNATEXT.", " ");

        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text Documents (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        sfd.FileName = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(sfd.FileName, newLines);
        }
```

Do remember that you need to have that EXACT string YNATEXT. (with a period in the end) for it to replace it.

Comment: I tried it again just now and it does replace the Word "YNATEXT." with a blank space. Are you sure you're hitting the right code when it's time for saving?

Comment: I tried to put in "YNATEXT. is a very specific Word that's forbidden! No more YNATEXT." and the output in the text file is " is a very specific Word that's forbidden! No more  "